# Is it possible to control font size in the tables while using rmarkdown/bookdown?

Tags: latex, r-markdown, markdown, knitr, bookdown

I'm using bookdown to prepare some documents.

For some reasons I need to have bigger font size for headings and main text and smaller font-size for tables.

The simple minimal reproducible example is below:

```
---
papersize: a6
geometry: 'landscape'
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2: 
    latex_engine: xelatex

header-includes:
- \usepackage[fontsize=15pt]{scrextend}

---

Below is a table with narrow first column and wide second column:

| **Seq** | **Description** |
|:---:|-------------|
| `1` | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. |
| `2` | Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. |
```

Link to [intermediate LaTeX file](https://pastebin.com/raw/GumryPck).

Is it possible to decrease font size for tables to make it smaller than now?

Comment: Can you include the intermediate .tex file?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/GumryPck) it is.

Comment: Thanks! Try with `\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{\tiny}` in your header includes

Comment: I have tested this in real long complicated document and it works great! Please post this idea as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can force a smaller font size for `longtable` by adding

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{\tiny}
```

to your `header-includes`